# Google URL Shortener example code to vb

Tags: vb.net

I am having difficulties to convert this code to vb.net

```
request.Queue<Event>(service.Url.Insert(
    new Url
        {
            LongUrl= "www.elnorte.com"
        },
     (content, error, i, message) =>
     {
         // Put your callback code here.
      });
```

I got this so far but I can't make it work.

```
Request.Queue(Of Url)(service.Url.Insert(newShortUrl), AddressOf OnResponse())
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What language is the code writen to?

Comment: The code es written in c#

Comment: I get converting error on all c# to vb.net converters

Comment: [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/batch), this is the code, I've tried several converters but it does not work

Comment: Does this piece of code you converted work?

Comment: No, the code from the converter does not work